# iOS can we fix the ISO and leave exposure time flexible when taking pictures with iPhone camera

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, iso

I was wondering is it possible to set the ISO and allow the device to choose the exposure time automatically?

We have this app that keeps taking photos as user moves his device. And according to Apple's documentation

iOS 8 seems to give us control of the iSO and exposure time:

```
- (void)setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:(CMTime)duration ISO:(float)ISO completionHandler:(void (^)(CMTime syncTime))handler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

However after trying this method, the exposure time didn't seem to automatically adjust.

Does anyone know if it is possible at all to do this?

Cheers!

Comment: you can check this answer will help you on your issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312634/strange-behaviour-after-modifying-exposure-duration-and-going-back-to-avcapturee

Comment: thanks! it was helpful!